# Call method on render page content from parent window WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window

I'm developing a page-based program so I have a main menu that loads a Basewindow that contains a frame with the page inside depending the specified uri as shown:

BaseWindow xaml code:

```
<Window ...>
    <Toolbar>
        <Button>
        </Button>
        <!--
            Same toolbar for all pages
        -->
    </Toolbar>

    <StackPanel Name="c">
        <Border BorderThickness="0,2,0,0">
            <Border.BorderBrush>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionColorKey}}"/>
            </Border.BorderBrush>
        </Border>

        <Frame Name="contentFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

BaseWindow C#:

```
public Uri FormUri {
    get => formUri;
    set {
        if (value != null) {
            formUri = value;
            //sets the content inside frame
            MainFrame.Navigate(formUri);
        }
    }
}

public BaseWindow(Uri formUri) {
    InitializeComponent();

    FormUri = formUri;

    MainFrame.ContentRendered += MainFrame_ContentRendered;
}

private void MainFrame_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    content = (IBasePage)MainFrame.Content;
}

public void FirstRegister() {
    content.FirstRegister();
}

/*
    some methods
*/
```

The problem is that I need to call `FirstRegister()` from outside this class and if the window is closed / content not loaded it throws an exception so what I suppose I need is to take the `MainFrame.ContentRendered` event and make it public and in the classes I need to call the content method do it inside the event signature.

This is the exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

in this line:

```
public void FirstRegister() {
    content.FirstRegister(); //<-- content
}
```

Comment: It's a private class variable

Comment: Where are you Calling the FirstRegister() method of the BaseWindow? Has the ContentRendered event being raised by then? Probably not.

Comment: Im' calling it from other class like this:

`var wind = new BaseWindow(uri);
wind.show();
wind.FirstRegister();
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait until the `ContentRendered` event for the `Frame` has been raised and your `content` field has been initialized before you call the method.

You could for example check if the `content` field has been initialized in your `FirstRegister()` method, and wait to call the `FirstRegister()` method until the `ContentRendered` event is raised if it hasn't:

```
public void FirstRegister()
{
    if (content != null)
    {
        content.FirstRegister();
    }
    else
    {
        MainFrame.ContentRendered += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (content != null)
                content.FirstRegister();
        };
    }
}
```

Or you could define a custom event in your `BaseWindow` class, raise this in the `MainFrame_ContentRendered` event handler and wait to call the method until it has been raised:

```
var wind = new BaseWindow(uri);
win.YourEvent += (ss,ee) => wind.FirstRegister();
wind.show();
```

Comment: I've not marked your answer as the correct one because I've done it some days ago but I forgot about this question so I write my entire solution.

Comment: So you basically copied my answer and wrote your own one...?

Comment: No no, as I hadn't got any answer I'd been trying until I wrote the code that I put here but I forgot to update this question and wrote the answer. When you answer today the stackexange app has notified me that I have a new comment and then I've remembered that I haven't written the answer.

Comment: It is not my intention to copy your code and say it is mine, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: I added mine because I solved the problem first. If you are not satisfied I can delete the post and mark yours as the correct

Comment: Done, sorry for the misunderstanding ;)